# Sequelize nested models

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this project with model structure of:

- Company

  - Users
  - Devices

    - Usage data
  - EndCustomer (Company)

Company model:

```
    var Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique:true
        },
        location: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
        });
    
        Company.associate = function(models) {
            models.Company.hasMany(models.Company, {
                as:'EndCustomer',
                foreignKey:'CompanyId'
            })
            models.Company.hasMany(models.User);
            models.Company.hasMany(models.Device);
        };
    
    return Company;
```

When logged in an user can query the usage data of the devices which belong to the same company with this kind of code

```
  models.UsageData.findAll({
    order: sequelize.literal("startTime DESC"),
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Device,
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: models.Company,
            required:true,
            include: [
              {
                model: models.User,
                required:true,
                attributes:[],
                where: {
                  id: *userid*,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
```

Now I need to find out how to query the Usage data of the devices belonging to EndCustomers which are owned by the parent Company and add the data to the first query.

I have tried this kind of code

```
  models.UsageData.findAll({
    order: sequelize.literal("startTime DESC"),
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Device,
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: models.Company,
            required:true,
            include: [
              {
                model: models.User,
                required:true,
                attributes:[],
                where: {
                  id: *userid*,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        model: models.Device,
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: models.Company,
            as:"EndCustomer",
            required:true,
            include: [
              {
                model: models.Company,
                required:true,
                include: [
                {
                model:models.User,
                required:true,
                where:{ id: *userid* }
                }
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  })
```

But this doesn't work as the association between Device and the EndCustomer company is wrong

I can create a workaround by creating a query where the company is on the top of the query e.g.:

```
models.Company.findOne({
      include:[
      {
      model: models.User,
      where: {id: *userid*},
      required:true      
      },
      {
        model:Device,
        /* Parent company usage data */
      },
      {
       model:models.Company,
       as:"EndCustomer",
       include:[
       model:models.Device
       /* EndCustomer usage data */       
       ]      
      }]
})
```

but this isn't good way because I also need to limit the rows of the UsageData .

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an association to access a parent organization:

```
models.Company.belongsTo(models.Company, {
                as:'Parent',
                foreignKey:'CompanyId'
            })
```

and then add it to `include` option:

```
{
        model: models.Device,
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: models.Company,
            required: true,
            include: [
              {
                model: models.Company,
                as: 'Parent',
                required: true,
                include: [
                 {
                   model: models.User,
                   required: true,
                   where:{ id: *userid* }
                 }
                ],
              },
            ],
          }
```

About combining two conditions: I'm just unsure that 2 included `Device` models would work together in the same query.